# YouTube's "Yes, it's made for kids" mean it is suitable for kids or it means it is "targeted" towards kids?

Tags: youtube

I felt the phrase somewhat vague but after months of "feeling it", it seems it means it is targeted towards kids, or made "specifically" for kids?

Likewise, the "No, it's not made for kids"... does it mean not suitable for kids, or not specifically for kids (meaning it is for everybody)? So my feeling is that it means "it is not specifically for kids".

Still, I don't know how it affects whether the video will get a narrower audience, or what are the resulting effects of choosing it?

Comment: Cool, I was about to ask the exact same question :D My audience isn't specifically kids, but they're certainly ok to watch and I'd hate to lose that part of my audience. Or vice versa.

Comment: I just noticed that after you select "Not made for kids," it gives you the drop down menu option to limit the audience to 18 years and up, or not.